# Cancel ContinueWith Task chain and report error to caller

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

If I have a “Login” command that needs to execute several  tasks, and I have code that looks like the following

```
public async void LoginAsync()
{
    await someService.Connect().ContinueWith(async (r) =>
    {
        //do some stuff with r.Result here
    })
    .ContinueWith(async (r) =>
    {
       //do some other stuff here
    })
    ContinueWith(async (r) =>
    {
       //do even more stuff here
    });
```

going down the happy path, the code executes as expected and everything is fine.

My question is, if there is a problem/exception in one of the tasks in the chain, how do I cancel the remaining tasks and report what went wrong to the caller?

I have tried throwing exceptions within the ContinueWith statements, but these are not caught by the try/catch block I put around the caller code.

I have read about CancellationTokenSource and that feels like it's on the right track, but trying to implement the example code on MSDN into this situation doesn't seem to work.

any pointers would be great

Kris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use `ContinueWith` at all here.  `await` each `Task` you want to create a continuation of instead, as that will give you the desired error handling semantics.

```
public async Task LoginAsync()
{
    var result = await someService.Connect();
    //do some stuff with r.Result here
    //do some other stuff here
    //do even more stuff here
}
```

Also note that a method like this should return a `Task`, allowing the caller to both know when the operation finishes, to be able to determine if it completed successfully and, if it faulted, to see the exception.